# Bootstrap - Div with boxed grid inside the .fluid-container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please check this two photos

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J3wQ.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJvek.jpg]

I don't know how to get ".myDivInTheGrid" in boxed bootstrap div. Any suggestions?

I have something like this...

```
<div class="fluid-container">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div><!-- Div with image -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="myDivInTheGrid"></div>
        </div><!-- div with content -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created a working example with a picture in the div you showed in the picture. I made it for `col-md-*` but you can do the same for larger grid system. If your screen is small, stretch the browser. Check it out [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/rORdJE?editors=110)

The code is like this:
**HTML**:

```
  body
  <div class="container-fluid">
     .fluid-container
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           .col-md-6
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                .col-md-6
            </div>
            <img class="row" src="http://s22.postimg.org/8z6hs0mch/Chrysanthemum.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body{
    background:#8EC34D;
    color: white;
 }

 .container-fluid {
    background: #81AD4B;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
 }

 .col-md-6 {
     background:#769C47;
     height: 300px;
  }

 img {
    width: 256px;
    height: 192px;
 }
```